# Prove $\exists_x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi) \iff (\forall_x\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ using natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I want to prove $\exists_x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi) \iff (\forall_x\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ where $x \notin FV(\psi)$ using natural deduction method. I was able to prove implication from left to right:
$$
{\exists_x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi) ~~~~~~~~{{[\phi[t/x]\rightarrow \psi]~~~~~~~ {{[\forall_x\phi(x)]}\over{\phi[t/x]}}} \over {\psi}}}\over{\psi \over {\forall_x\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi}}
$$

but I am not able to prove implicatin from right to left. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguing informally in natural deduction style, assume as premiss

> $\forall x\phi(x) \to \psi$

Now remember that that is elementarily equivalent to

> $\neg\forall x\phi(x) \lor \psi$

So the obvious brute force proof strategy is to argue by cases. You need to show, first, that $\neg\forall x\phi(x)$ implies $\exists x(\phi(x) \to \psi)$. But we have

> $\neg\forall x\phi(x)\\ \exists x\neg\phi(x)\\ \quad|\quad \neg\phi(a)\\ \quad|\quad \phi(a) \to \psi \\ \quad|\quad \exists x(\phi(x) \to \psi) \\  \exists x(\phi(x) \to \psi) $

using existential quantifier elimination at the key step. And now you need to show that $\psi$ implies $\exists x(\phi(x) \to \psi)$. But that's easy, we just need to fill in the proof

> $\psi\\ \phi(a) \to \psi \\ \exists x(\phi(x) \to \psi) $

So put everything together and we are done, in this informal Fitch-style presentation.

It remains to massage the proof into your preferred tree layout: exercise!

Comment: After unrolling all equivalences into proper natural deduction rules it would produce quite lengthy proof.

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove :

> $(∀xϕ(x)→ψ) \rightarrow ∃x(ϕ(x)→ψ)$

using *Natural Deduction* without "abbreviations".

---

*Proof* :

*1)* $\phi(x)$ --- assumed [1]

*2)* $\lnot \phi(x)$ --- assumed [2]

*3)* $\bot$ --- 1), 2) : $\rightarrow$E

*4)* $\psi$ --- 3) : $\bot$E

*5)* $\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi$ --- 1) and 4) : $\rightarrow$I, discharging [1]

*6)* $\exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ --- 5) : $\exists$I

*7)* $\lnot \exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ --- assumed [3]

*8)* $\bot$ --- 6), 7) : $\rightarrow$E

*9)* $\phi(x)$ --- 2), 8) : *RAA*, discharging [2]

*10)* $\forall \phi(x)$ --- 9) : $\forall$I

*11)* $\forall \phi(x) \rightarrow \psi$ --- assumed [4]

*12)* $\psi$ --- 10), 11) : $\rightarrow$E

*13)* $\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi$ --- 12) : $\rightarrow$I

*14)* $\exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ --- 13) : $\exists$I

*15)* $\bot$ --- 14), 7) : $\rightarrow$E

*16)* $\exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ --- 7), 15) : *RAA*, discharging [3]

> > $\vdash (∀xϕ(x)→ψ) \rightarrow \exists x(\phi(x) \rightarrow \psi)$ --- 1), 16) : $\rightarrow$I

---

*Notes*

*A)* In the above proof we have only one application of $\forall$I (step 10); in that step, the only undischarged assumption is [3], where $x$ is not free. Thus, contrary to the other "direction", the proviso : $x \notin FV(\psi)$ is not necessary.

*B)* In the derivation we have used *RAA*: this use is essential, as shown by the fact that : $(∀xϕ(x)→ψ) \rightarrow ∃x(ϕ(x)→ψ)$ is not *intuitionistically valid*.

Answer (score -1):

Well, $\exists x \phi(x) \rightarrow \psi$ is not logically equivalent to $\forall x \phi(x) \rightarrow \psi$. If every $x$ has some property, certainly there exists an $x$ with that property. However, just because some $x$ has a property does not mean every $x$ has a property.

Unless your domain of discourse has only one element.

Edit: or if $\phi(x)$ is always false.

Comment: Note the bracketing in the OP's question.